# a lack of examples of using libmodbus functions

Tags: modbus

I am new to modbus. I have spent hours reading the Help(?) files, which never seem to give you an example! I am using C on a Raspberry Pi, model3 and have installed libmodbus. I am trying to talk to an epSolar solar panel controller via an FTDI USB to RS485 converter.
The epSolar docs say that the Read Input registers start at address 3000 and continue to 311D. I am trying to read 3104.
I modified the code below. It connects to the device but trying to read input register 0x04 always returns -1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <modbus.h>

enum {TCP, RTU};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int socket;
 modbus_t *ctx;
 modbus_mapping_t *mb_mapping;
 int rc;
 int use_backend;
 int i;
 uint16_t tab_reg[64];
 use_backend = RTU;

 printf("Waiting for Serial connection\n");
 ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/SOLAR", 115200, 'N', 8, 1);
 modbus_set_slave(ctx, 0);
 //modbus_connect(ctx);
 if(modbus_connect(ctx) == -1)
  {
   fprintf(stderr, "Serial connection failed: 
            %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
   modbus_free(ctx);
   return -1;
  }

 printf("Serial connection started!\n");

 mb_mapping = modbus_mapping_new(MODBUS_MAX_READ_BITS, 0,
                                MODBUS_MAX_READ_REGISTERS, 0);
 if(mb_mapping == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate the mapping: %s\n",
              modbus_strerror(errno));
   modbus_free(ctx);
   return -1;
  }
  rc = modbus_read_input_registers(ctx, 1, 0x0A, tab_reg);
  if(rc == -1)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
    return -1;
   }

  for(i=0; i < rc; i++)
   printf("reg[%d]=%d (0x%X)\n", i, tab_reg[i], tab_reg[i]);
  modbus_mapping_free(mb_mapping);
  modbus_free(ctx);
  modbus_close(ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

It connects fine and allocates the mapping, but rc is always -1 with error message that the port has timed out.
I have run out of ideas and feel like I am navigating through treacle!

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: **modbus_set_slave(ctx, 0);** modbus swlave ID 0 is invalid, valid modbus slave IDs are 1-247

Comment: More particularly, modbus slave ID 0 is the broadcast ID. Most devices won't directly respond on the RTU wire to a broadcast message. You'll need to address the device by its correct slave ID in order to get it to return data to you

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to Modbus. With my current experience, make sure you are allocating enough memory for the `tab_reg`  for storing the results. Also try setting the Debug mode on i.e **`modbus_set_debug(ctx, TRUE);`** to Check for the request and response code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but hopefully this answer will help anyone who lands here via a Google search.

I can see a few points that need some help.

As commented by Saad above, the modbus server ID above is incorrect.  ID 0 is reserved for broadcast messages, which a slave will not respond to.  Find out what the Modbus ID for the target device is, and use that.

I think what's tricking you is that you'll also always get a proper "connect" as long as the serial port you provided is valid.  This isn't a connection to any particular device so much as it's a connection to the Modbus network port.  You're getting a timeout because a response was expected by libmodbus, but no response was received on the wire.

There are several other little troubles in the code presented, but given the age of this post I almost feel like I'm nitpicking something the OP probably already solved.  The big problem is the unworkable slave ID.  Other minor problems include:  unnecessary use of modbus_mapping (struct for use on server/slaves), possible misallocation of modbus_mapping (no space allocated for input registers).